# How to issue a command to all the lines in a visual block?

Tags: vim

How can I perform something like `dtR` (delete until you meet the `R` in the line) across all the lines in a linewise visual block, or say, for the next `n` lines?

### The long story

Let's suppose there is the following piece of code:

```
L0 = Rotated_Shape((1, 0), (-1, 0), (-1, 1))
L90 = Rotated_Shape((0, -1), (0, 1), (1, 1))
L180 = Rotated_Shape((-1, 0), (1, 0), (1, -1))
L270 = Rotated_Shape((0, 1), (0, -1), (-1, -1))

O0 = Rotated_Shape((1, 0), (1, -1), (0, -1))
O90 = Rotated_Shape((0, -1), (-1, -1), (-1, 0))
O180 = Rotated_Shape((-1, 0), (-1, 1), (0, 1))
O270 = Rotated_Shape((0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0))

S0 = Rotated_Shape((-1, 0), (0, -1), (1, -1))
S90 = Rotated_Shape((0, 1), (-1, 0), (-1, -1))
S180 = Rotated_Shape((1, 0), (0, 1), (-1, 1))
S270 = Rotated_Shape((0, -1), (1, 0), (1, 1))

T0 = Rotated_Shape((0, 1), (-1, 0), (1, 0))
T90 = Rotated_Shape((1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1))
T180 = Rotated_Shape((0, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0))
T270 = Rotated_Shape((-1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1))

Z0 = Rotated_Shape((1, 0), (0, -1), (-1, -1))
Z90 = Rotated_Shape((0, -1), (-1, 0), (-1, 1))
Z180 = Rotated_Shape((-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1))
Z270 = Rotated_Shape((0, 1), (1, 0), (1, -1))
```

I am now reworking this code and I want all these lines to become what is on the right side of the equation (assignment), i. e. delete the variable names, the equal sign and keep only the `Rotated_Shape((...` part.

I guess the best way to do this particular case is to search and replace a regular expression, but my first approach I didn't know how to do was to use the blockwise-visual or line-visual mode for each four of them and do something like `dtR` (delete until you meet the `R` in the line).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can highlight those lines with a visual block and then use `:help 'normal'`.

The end result post-select looks something like: `:'<,'>normal dtR`

You can also abbreviate `normal` to `norm`.

Comment: Use `normal!` please

Comment: I prefer to not use `normal!` in quick ex commands like this because I often want them to use the mappings to mimic what they'd do in normal mode regardless (because that's what I'm used to when editing at full speed).

If writing a script that uses `:normal`, I'd definitely advise using `normal!` instead.

Comment: And yet for an SO answer, `normal!`  is still preferable. You don’t want user mappings to interfere here (unless thats an explicit goal of the answer, which is not the case).